# How to Get device timezone?

Tags: swift, timezone

I use the following code for getting the device timezone

```
func getCurrentTimeZone() -> String{

         return TimeZone.current.identifier

  }

  let currentTimeZone = getCurrentTimeZone()
   print(currentTimeZone)
```

It gives the location e.g. "Asia/Dhaka", but I want to get in the "+02:00 or -04:30" format.
How can I convert the value to the desired format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired format appears to be in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC), in which case you can use `ISO8601DateFormatter`:

```
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withTimeZone, .withColonSeparatorInTimeZone]
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
let formattedTimezone = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Note that I have used `Date()` in the last line. This will output the offset from GMT of the timezone at the current instant. Replace this with a `Date` of your choice to get the offset from GMT of that timezone at *that* `Date` instead.